# How to handle redirect request

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-b2c

I've created everything in B2C, and can call a URL (using `Response.Redirect()` from my asp.net page_load method) to display the [Microsoft] login screen.

After the User successfully logs in, the browser gets redirected to the supplied redirect_url (another asp.net page), as expected.

What I can't find is any guidance on how to handle that redirection request in order to extract the details about the logged-in user (the 'claims' I set in b2c).

I included the following `&response_type=code+id_token` in the URL and can see that both get included in the `Request.Params` collection.

I can't now find the docs which described how to create the URL which I'm calling. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks.

Here's the full redirect instruction, for completeness' sake (but there is AFAIK no issue with this):

```
        Response.Redirect("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" +
                          AuthenticationConstants.Tenant.ToString() +
                          "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=" +
                          AuthenticationConstants.PolicySignIn.ToString() +
                          "&client_id=" +
                          AuthenticationConstants.ClientID.ToString() +
                          "&redirect_uri=" +
                          Server.HtmlEncode("https://localhost:44301/auth/Login.aspx") +
                          "&response_mode=query" +
                          "&response_type=code+id_token" +
                          "&scope=openid " + AuthenticationConstants.ClientID.ToString()
                         );
```

Comment: Have you tried [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi)?

Comment: Ok, I can see some data in the response, and by splitting it and Base64 decoding it, can see things like the UserId. What I cannot see are the Custom Attributes I added to the Claims.

Comment: I would start here: https://jwt.ms/.  Put your token in there, do you see them?

Answer (score 0):

The claims you set in B2C are included in the id_token.
ASP.Net makes these available for you via `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst('nameOfTheClaim')`.

From the [Azure AD B2C guide for an ASP.Net Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi):

```cs
 // Controllers\HomeController.cs

 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Claims()
 {
     Claim displayName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().NameClaimType);
     ViewBag.DisplayName = displayName != null ? displayName.Value : string.Empty;
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm not using the OWIN libraries, nor the MVC pattern. I'm guessing that ClaimsPrincipal is in one of those libraries, but the article doesn't make this at all clear.

Comment: Can you update your question to include names of libraries and sample code, otherwise it's hard to help you out.